# Using a kubernetes ingress to support multiple sub domains

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, ssl-certificate, subdomain, kubernetes-ingress

I have a domain foobar. When I started my project, I knew I would have my webserver handling traffic for `foobar.com`. Also, I plan on having an elasticsearch server I wanted running at `es.foobar.com`. I purchased my domain at GoDaddy and I (maybe prematurely) purchased a single site certificate for `foobar.com`. I can't change this certificate to a wildcard cert. I would have to purchase a new one. I have my DNS record routing traffic for that simple URL. I'm managing everything using Kubernetes.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to use my simple single-site certificate for the main site and subdomains like my elasticsearch server or do I need to purchase another single-site certificate specifically for the elasticsearch server? I checked earlier and GoDaddy wants $350 for the multisite one.
2. ElasticSearch complicates this somewhat since if it's being accessed at `es.foobar.com`  and the cert is for `foobar.com` it's going to reject any requests, right? Elasticsearch needs a cert in order to have solid security.

Comment: Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider?

Comment: Cloud, DigitalOcean

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use my simple single-site certificate for the main site and subdomains?

To achieve your goal, you can use [`Name based virtual hosting ingress`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#name-based-virtual-hosting), since most likely your webserver `foobar.com` and elasticsearch `es.foobar.com` work on different ports and will be available under the same IP.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: name-virtual-host-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foobar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: webserver
            port:
              number: 80
  - host: es.foobar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: elastic
            port:
              number: 9200-9300 #http.port parametr in elastic config
```

It can also be implemented using [TLS private key and certificate](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#tls) and and creating a file for TLS. This is possible for just one level, like `*.foobar.com`.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: name-virtual-host-ingress
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - foobar.com
      - es.foobar.com
      secretName: "foobar-secret-tls"
  rules:
  - host: foobar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: webserver
            port:
              number: 80
  - host: es.foobar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: elastic
            port:
              number: 9200-9300 #http.port parametr in elastic config
```

Either you need to get a wildcard or separate certificate for another domain.

Comment: Could you answer me, did my decision help you? If yes, you could follow [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) recommendations for evaluating responses.

Comment: Could your TLS solution work if the domain is identical (foobar.com) just the ports are different?

Comment: Above, I propose a subdomain solution based on the Kubernetes and code parts are examples.